# Is there way for creating progress bar for control my task step accomplishment

Tags: html, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I have project in Laravel for tasks management , all i want is to add progress bar to controlling my task status from beginning until complete, I add in tasks table column call progress which content integer number to that define task progress and I add progress bar in view like :

```
<progress id="file" value="32" max="100" style="width: 542px;"> 32% </progress>
```

Comment: Hi Ayman. I am note sure what question you are asking. What happens when you add the progress bar? Is there any error output?

Comment: Is your task processed `server-side` or `client-side` ? If it is `client-side` like : Fill some forms, it will be simple to compute the advancement of your process, and improve % of your progressbar. If it is `server-side`, it will be more tricky, and it depends on the nature of your process. Please improve your question.

Comment: @Tom  
I have a task management system that I want to add mechanism to show the status of task progress in progress bar how to achieve that

Comment: @Devart yes i have in server side using Laravel controller and in database i have column name progress which integer type and in client side i have progress bar which have the progress bar value from database column so how to calculate task progress?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to edit your question, but queue is full.

So if I understand well, you have a `backend table` **tasks** with a column **progress**.
Then you want to display all tasks in a `frontend table` with a designed `progress-bar`.

### Need more clarity :

- How the database `progress` column is filled ? Is it background/system tasks, with **real-time** or **step-by-step** progress ?
- Have you issues on **displaying** or **updating** your progress-bar values ?
- What do you mean when you say :

> how to calculate task progress

### Ways to achieve your goal

Accurate : Use websockets to detect progress changes on your tasks, and update the progress-bar value.
May be less accurate : Or Request periodically your database by ajax to update progress-bar(s) value.

Comment: i have one progress column on my task to update progress bar value  to be updated  i want best way to update progress column value